# Java build path not updated with pom dependencies

Tags: java, spring, maven

I  updated the pom.xml to spring 3.0.1.RELEASE instead of Spring 2.x.x .

So when I did 'mvn clean install', the lib directory in my target directory was correctly updated with the right jar files.

But when I do a right click on my project and then go to "Build Path", I notice that I have the old dependencies of spring and not the dependencies for spring 3.0.

How can I update the Java Build Path?

Comment: did you mean in eclipse ?

Comment: There could be cache folders involved in this, but if you give a better description of your development environment (OS and IDE would be a good start), we'll be more likely to give you a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

If this is eclipse (you are using), then you need to update the Eclipse project file from the .pom file. That is done by doing the following command:

> mvn eclipse:eclipse

After that, refresh project in eclipse and you will see that eclipse recognises the dependencies from the pom file.